# Matrix that shows how close indices are to each other

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a vector of n words, not all distinct.

```
[the, quick, brown, fox, jumps, over, the, lazy, dog]
```

From this, I want to make an n×n matrix that shows how closely the words are related. Words that are adjacent are more closely related than words that are far apart. Words that are two words apart are more closely related than words that are three words apart, and so on.

The tricky part comes when there are repeated words. "The" appears twice in the example. Notice that "quick" appears one place from the first "the" and *five* places from the second "the," whereas "lazy" is one and *six* places from them. Consequently, (the, quick) should have a higher relationship value than (the, lazy).

This example uses words, but the concept is applicable to many things. Is there some kind of analysis, operation, transformation, etc. that I can use to find relationship values like what I have described?

Note: The values do not need to be absolute. They don't need to be consistent between different matrices. They only need to be higher or lower within the matrix itself. If there's a way to compare values within a single matrix to say how *much* higher or lower they are, that'd be great, but it's not really necessary.

Comment: To resolve this kind of issue could you not just take the average of the distances, if multiple instances of the same word exists?

Comment: That's a little different from what I had been looking for, but the more I think about it, the more I like your approach. Consider the vector [a, b, a, c]. The average distance from 'c' to 'a' is two. The average distance from 'c' to 'b' is also two. I would have expected 'c' to be more closely related to 'a' because it is right next to an 'a' AND has another 'a' three places away, whereas the 'b' is further. On the other hand, for the words example, averaging reduces the impact of too-common words, which could be quite handy. It could make (fish, wet) stand a better chance against (fish, it).

Comment: You could weight the averages somehow, to avoid the issue you gave in the vector example, I guess. I'm not sure exactly what you're after, so I couldn't give a specific example. :)